# Js load time minimization by putting all into a single file

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have checked load time of my js libs (about 10 of them) and noticed that more of half of loading time is negotiation with server for next file.

So I had put all js libs into one file, which is 366kb of minified js code, and loading time now is much better.

But I wonder is it really so good idea as it looks?

Could such heavy js code in a single file cause browser lag or freeze on older PCs? Or any other pitfalls are there?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/222403/why-not-embed-styles-scripts-in-html-instead-of-linking. One benefit to having multiple files is that you can change one of them and force a cache-reload of only that one file. If you have one mammoth file, a small change forces a reload of the whole giant file. Whether such a problem is a realistic issue for your site depends on how it is architected.

Comment: I've found one pitfall: browser can't put js loading in parallel, and sometimes it's really takes faster to load wit separated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's a good idea. I've only seen problems happen in these 2 ways:

1) If you don't write your code properly (semicolons, etc), then minifying can occasionally cause problems, because it can't separate the scripts properly when executing.

This isn't too common, and you'll see it quickly, when you have errors in your minified version only.

2) We saw an issue in IE when you combined too many files (I think it was in the twenties) we had to split them out because IE has a limit for how large a single JS file could be.

That may have been an older version of IE and you may never run into that.

PS: This used to be a hard rule that Steve Souders made popular. Since then, he's become less dogmatic about it, as browsers are getting better and more efficient at downloading several files in parallel.

PPS: Specifics on IE rule-per-stylesheet limitations:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using one minified js file is **completely fine**. Of course some would say that it's theoretically not a good practice. However in practise you sometimes have to do some "ugly" hacks to achieve better performance.